# Memory issue in C where data is being overwritten

Tags: c, memory-leaks, memory-management

I've the following program:

```
// required include statements...

static char ***out;

char* get_parameter(char* key)
{
    char *querystr = /*getenv("QUERY_STRING")*/ "abcdefg=abcdefghi";
    if (querystr == NULL)
        return (void*)0;

    char s[strlen(querystr)] ;
    strcpy(s, querystr);
    const char delim = '&';
    const char delim2 = '=';
    static size_t size = 0;
    if (out == 0)
    {
        out = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));
        size = split(s, &delim, out);
    }

    int i=0;
    for (; i<size; i++)
    {
        if ((*out)[i] != NULL)
        {
            char ***iout = NULL;
            iout = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));
            int isize = split((*out)[i], &delim2, iout);

            if (isize > 1 && ((*iout)[1]) != NULL && strcmp(key, (*iout)[0]) == 0)
            {
                size_t _size = strlen((*iout)[1]);
                char* value = (char*) malloc(_size*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(value, (*iout)[1]);
                free(iout);
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
    return (void*) 0;
}

static size_t count(const char *str, char ch)
{
    if (str == NULL) return 0;
    size_t count = 1;
    while (*str)
        if (*str++ == ch) count++;
    return count;
}

size_t split(const char *const str, const char* delim, char ***out)
{
    size_t size = count(str, *delim);
    *out = calloc(size, sizeof(char));
    char* token = NULL;
    char* tmp = (char*) str;
    int i=0;
    while ((token = strtok(tmp, delim)) != NULL)
    {
        tmp = NULL;
        (*out)[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof strlen(token));
        strcpy((*out)[i++], token);
    }
    return size;
}

main()
{
    char* val = get_parameter("abcdefg");
    printf("%s\n", val);  // it should prints `abcdefghi`, but it prints `abcd?`
    free(val);
}
```

as appears in the main method, the function get_parameter should prints `abcdefghi`, but it prints `abcd?` where `?` is a controls character with value of 17.

Why the reset of string is not printed? I think I mis-used the `malloc` to allocate appropriate space.

Also, is there any tool that I can use to know the internal representation of memory for my pointers?

Answer (score 4):

You're dealing with C-Strings here. You must consider 1 additional byte for the NULL-termination ('\0')

Therefore:

```
char s[strlen(querystr)] ;
strcpy(s, querystr);
```

Is incorrect.

`strlen` will return 4 for string "abcd" but what you want is to allocate space for "abcd\0"

So you need strlen + 1

Comment: do the changes and still have the problem. And how `querystr` is not NULL terminated? what I know that any "str" is null terminated by compiler

Comment: I have add `+1` to the result of `strlen` in all the code ,but still I've the problem. the problem is only solved when I replaced the line:  `(*out)[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof strlen(token));` with `(*out)[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof strlen(token) * sizeof(char*));`

Comment: Your "count" method is wrong. It will return 1 for an empty string, it will return 2 for "abcd=abcd" with ch '='

Comment: Yea, I should modify it to be like `str == NULL || strlen(str) == 0`

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
out = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));

iout = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

are a problem.

`sizeof()` returns the number of bytes required to store an object of the given type, in this case, the size of a pointer (to a `char`).  `malloc()` then allocates that many bytes (apparently 4 bytes on your architecture).  To fix this, you need to give `malloc` the desired string length instead of using `sizeof`.

Additionally, the line

```
char* value = (char*) malloc(_size*sizeof(char));
```

has a completely unnecessary use of `sizeof()`.  `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed by the standard to be 1.

Comment: which line(s) you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You should use gdb to run your binary step by step and see what's wrong.
Valgrind is a very good tools, it will tell you what's line overwrite in memory, etc..